# Body of request received on Express backend is different than how i sent it from React frontend

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to send a post request from my React front end to my Express front end, for some reason, the object I want to recieve, is being displayed so that the object is the key of another object and the value is and empty string.

Here is my onSubmit React function

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const backend = '/api/login'

    fetch(backend, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })
        .then(res => {
            res.json()
        })
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })

}`
```

And my post function on the express server

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)

})
```

For example, if the object I want to send is `{username: "user1", password: "password"}`, when I `console.log(req.body)`, I get `{ '{"username":"user1","password":"password"}': '' }` in the console.

How do i fix this so i get the object that I requested?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is JSON format. To parse it you can use:
`JSON.parse('{"username":"user1","password":"password"}')`
or `JSON.parse(req.body)`

Comment: No its not in JSON format, if i parse it, I get an error basically saying its not JSON

Answer (score 0):

The approach is fine with `JSON.stringify()` because it should be posted just like a string to the server. But if you want it to be an object at the backend then you have to parse it back with:

```
const userObj = JSON.parse(req.body.Data); // it will parse it back as an object
```

Comment: The object has already been parsed, if i try and parse it i get an error.

Comment: I kind of fixed it by using a for in statement then setting the key to a new variable. But i am still confused why the object i want is set to an empty string

Comment: I also think you have to change the header to use content type to json instead of form url encoded.

Comment: Before this issue i was having trouble getting the request body to display, it kept on being an empty object, i tried using content type json but it didnt work. form url encoded is the only thing that works

Comment: Also i can see that the key is `Data` so at your backend you should get it with `req.body.Data`.

Comment: Sorry I removed the Data part actually, i will update my question

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body can you check if these are set? or could you add the backend part too.

Comment: Yes they are set just like documentation

Comment: I just think its odd how i get a json object within a normal object, i've never seen that

Comment: Generally i send a key for the specific data to get it at the backend. Just like you did before with `Data` key. This will be referred to parse.

Comment: Yeah thats what I tried to do but it just got included within the object as json